# Minicart icon showing twice during checkout

Tags: mini-cart, checkout-page, magento2.4.4, js-css

Minicart is showing under sign in link during checkout. See screenshot.

Disabled current theme and applied luma and blank. All themes show the same?
[image]

I believe this is where it is coming from. Tried removing the block in my custom default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Squareup_Omni::css/loyalty-main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="squareup.checkout.express" template="Squareup_Omni::checkout-info.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Squareup\Omni\ViewModel\CheckoutConfig</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Squareup\Omni\Block\Payment\Form\Javascript" name="squareup_omni_payment_form_javascript" template="Squareup_Omni::payment/form/javascript.phtml" ifconfig="payment/squareup_payment/active" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block name="squareup.loyalty.bar" class="Squareup\Omni\Block\Frontend\Bar" after="header-wrapper"  ifconfig="loyalty/general/loyalty_bar" template="Squareup_Omni::loyalty/bar.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="express.container" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Squareup_Omni/minicart/content</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="checkout-express-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Squareup_Omni/js/view/payment/checkout/checkout-express</item>
                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Squareup_Omni/payment/checkout/checkoutexpress</item>
                                            <item name="componentContainer" xsi:type="string">mini-cart</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first minicart icon comes from `header-wrapper` block (block name declared in layout xml file) which contains: Logo, search, minicart,...

Looks like you add that block (`header-wrapper`) into a layout xml file in your custom module/3rd-party module, so it caused the checkout page to include `header-wrapper` block.

If you trying to modify the header, tell us what you want to achieve, we'll help.

Comment: It is coming from a 3rd-party module but not sure what file is causing the problem. Trying to display the standard format (Remove the search and minicart from header)

Comment: You can run this command to find modules that reference to `header-wrapper` block: `grep -r header-wrapper app vendor`.

Comment: I don't think I can use that command on localhost?

Comment: You can use that command on the terminal in Linux/MacOS.